# Можно ли с помощью скрипта обновить сессию в моем виджете при загрузке на страницу?

Tags: сессия, input, доступ, обновления, ucoz

В системе UCOZ, при добавление материала есть такой тег **INPUT** который в нем в **VALUE** обновляется **SSID** каждый перезагрузке страницу, и когда заходит какой то посетитель на эту страницу добавление материала, здесь есть штатный код $BODY$ , это называется в системе **UCOZ** оператор, но жаль чтоб в эту оператор, нет доступа через админ панели, содержимое этого оператора видно, только при загрузке страницу, через функции браузера **посмотреть код**.

А мне нужно было чтоб сделать изменение в этом операторе, не которые дополнительные  функции, я этого сделал написал виджет скрипт который загружает на страницу тела оператора переделенные мною, все работает как надо, но проблема в том что, в теле этого оператора есть такой невидимый тег,
который  в нем обновляется **VALUE**

```
<input type="hidden" name="ssid" value="E4ncRs9e">
```

если это тег находится в моем виджете при загрузке страницу не обновляется в нем **VALUE**, из за это при отправке материал на сервер, выдает ошибку **Доступ запрещен. Истек период сессии.**.
Такой вопрос? можно ли с помощью скрипта сделать чтоб обновился сессия в моем виджете при загрузке на страницу? вот ссылка на ту страницу [добавление материала](http://avtousta.ucoz.com/board/0-0-0-0-1)

Comment: Перед отправкой слать запрос на страницу, где есть этот ssid, получать его и вставлять в Ваш виджет. Не?

Comment: @ModaL вот есть такой код  `<input type="hidden" name="ssid" value="<?substr($BODY$,strrpos($BODY$,'ssid')+13,8)?>">`  можно с его помощью получит значение VALUE обновленным сессии из сервера, но тут есть не обновленная VALUE сессии который лежит в моем виджете, если это код поставить на мой виджет! при загрузке  страницу с виджета это код `<?substr($BODY$,strrpos($BODY$,'ssid')+13,8)?>` не будет сработать, потому что это код работает только в конструкторе UCOZ, ест такой вариант сделать так. это тег ставить в конструктор, чтоб получит ssid value и с помощью скрипта взят поставить на виджет

Comment: @ModaL Пример вот так, эту ставлю в конструктор `<input type="hidden" name="ssid" value="<?substr($BODY$,strrpos($BODY$,'ssid')+13,8)?>">` получил обновленный value, а это лежит в виджете `<input id="ssidin" type="hidden" name="ssid" value="">` с пустыми валуе, теперь нужно помощь скрипта полученный валуе взят и поставить в пустой валу который в виджете, пока события не вставился в дом, а то не получится, потому пока виджет загрузится , уже оператор делает свою делу. А я со скриптами не очень, по этому прощу помощь .

Comment: Как я понимаю, нужно просто получить значение оригинального ssid. Это можно сделать так: `$('input[name="ssid"]:eq(1)').val();`. Желательно конечно в Вашем виджете убрать `name="ssid"` и получить ssid так: `$('input[name="ssid"]').val();`

Comment: @ModaL можно готовы скрипт откуда куда? и еще не получится убрать `name="ssid"` потому что сервер не будет принимать без него,    вы просто помогите мне так, вот допустим я получил обновленный сессию таким образом   `<input id="ssidin" type="hidden" name="ssid" value="Тут новый ид сессия">` в конструкторе, и когда виджет загрузится взят это  **Тут новый ид сессия** вставит сюда `<input id="ssidin" type="hidden" name="ssid" value="Пустая сессия в виджете">`, просто надо так сделать чтоб при загрузке страницу это все получилось автоматически , если можно готовый скрипт пожалуйста .

Comment: Сейчас в Вашем исходном коде есть это `<input id="ssidout" type="hidde" name="ssid" value="">`. Что оно означает? И где хранится реальный session_id, в прошлый раз я его видел, а сейчас где он?

Comment: И ещё, где находится виджет? Визуально как его определить?

Comment: @ModaL сейчас я его открою, и уберу `type="hiden"` временно чтоб вы видели

Comment: Исходя из Ваших слов: `$('#ssidin').val($('#ssidout').val());`

Comment: Ну или так: `var widget_load = setInterval(function() {
 if($('#ssidin').size() > 0) {
  clearInterval(widget_load);
  
  $('#ssidin').val($('#ssidout').val());
 }
}, 100);`

Comment: @ModaL спасибо за помощь! вот  эту `$('#ssidin').val($('#ssidout').val());`  попробовал   отлично работает, как и гости , так и как пользователь , но когда заходишь как пользователь, какой то не понятный INPUT появляется который мне не известно. вот она `<input ty"="">`. Если вам не трудно залогинитесь как пользователь через соц сет посмотрите пож. что это как то появляется

Comment: @ModaL  спасибо эту тоже решил с помощью `div style display none` это создавался автоматический из за это почему то `<?substr($BODY$,strrpos($BODY$,'ssid')+13,21)?>`

Comment: Это Ваша конструкция `<?substr($BODY$,strrpos($BODY$,'ssid')+13,21)?>` так вырезала **ssid**. При авторизации как пользователь он короче: `K70T8Pyo`. У uCoz же есть условные операторы, можно задать, если гость, то 21 символ, если пользователь, то 8.

Comment: @ModaL да при гости показывает 21 - цифры , а при пользователя 7, и цифры и буквы , а тут код +13,21 для того чтоб на обоих работал , когда пользователь, обрезает и создает доп инпут, но не чего страшного, так и работает, я спрятал  уже его, Спасибо огромное вам.

Comment: @ModaL да правильно говорите можно сделать так, с помощью условных операторов.

Comment: @ModaL Спасибо вам ! здесь тоже помогли, вот так сделал, `<input id="ssidout" type="hidden" name="ssid" value="<?if($USER_LOGGED_IN$)?><?substr($BODY$,strrpos($BODY$,'ssid')+13,8)?><?else?><?substr($BODY$,strrpos($BODY$,'ssid')+13,21)?><?endif?>"> ` . Отлично! больше не появился не какой инпут,